# regex pattern fails for length of intermediate string

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if the string provided by the user starts with **abc** and ends with **de** with 4 characters in between like

```
"abc<4 characters>de".
```

I tried using pattern **("^abc.*(4)de$")**

But it fails for the 4 characters in middle. Is there any problem with pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say you need exactly four characters, you can use one of those:

```
"^abc.{4}de$"
"^abc....de$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `()` brackets with `{}`

```
^abc.{4}de$
```

which means that the matching word *should start with **abc** and end with **de** and in between there should be excactly 4 characters.*

A simpler solution is just to place a `.` between the `start` and the `end` pattern to describe that there should be exactly four characters:

```
^abc....de$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression :

```
^abc.{4}de$
```

`.{4}` is exactly what it seems : any character (`.`) exactly 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

Modify RegEx to following

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^abc.{4}de$");
         Matcher m = p.matcher("abc11111de");
         boolean b = m.matches();
         System.out.println(b);
```